# How to print a Panda DataFrame in Jupyter Notebook where it doesn't print the Index or the Column Name

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I know how to remove the Index, using the .to_string(index=False). But I'm not able to figure out how to remove the column names.

```py
matrix = [
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
]
def print_sudoku(s):
    df = pd.DataFrame(s)
    dff = df.to_string(index=False)
    print(dff)
print_sudoku(matrix)
```

The result is this.

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

I want to remove the first row, which is the row of column names.

Comment: A reminder to accept the correct answer if you got what you needed ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `header=False` when converting to string: `df.to_string(index=False, header=False)`

ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I didn't know about this. I can accept this answer in 8 minutes.